# How to make multiple divs inline responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have created a video player controls but I want to know how can I make it responsive as to make only the scrubber move but the play button or volume button to stay in the same place and keep the same distance?

*CSS*

```
#videoControls{
  height:8%;
  top:92%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#d92a2e;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transition: top .5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: top .5s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: top .5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: top .5s ease-in;
  transition: top .5s ease-in;
}

[class^="col-"] ,[class*= " col-"]{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.col-80{
  width: 80%;
}

.col-7-5{
  width: 32px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.col-7-6{
  width: 7.5%;
}

.col-5{
  width: 5%;
}
```

*HTML*

```html
<div class='controls' id='videoControls'>
  <div class='col-5'>
    <div class='btnGrp'>
      <div id='play' class='playBtn'></div>
      <div id='pause' class='pauseBtn'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-80'>
    <div id='scrubber'>
      <div id='track'></div>
      <div id='handle' class='draggable'></div>
      <div id='handle2' class=''></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-7-5'>
    <div class='btnGrp'>
      <div id='mute' class='muteBtn'></div>
      <div id='unmute' class='unmuteBtn'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-7-6'>
    <div id='timeDisplay'>
      <span id='currentTime'></span>
      &nbsp;&sol;&nbsp;
      <span id='duration'></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to a live version of this? This code on it's own isn't much to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/paw1qws5/

Comment: Your code happens to be just tags. Could you add some content in it so that we can see what element is where at the moment and where do you want them to be?

Comment: I edited  - I hope I translated "rager the scruber" correctly

Comment: here is a small example http://jsfiddle.net/paw1qws5/1/ If you try to resize the box you will see that all elements are resposive. I want to have the red and blue line fixed one in each corner and the only line to become short or long is the black line

Answer (score 0):

I have created the Responsive design if you have multiple div when you re-size the browser?

Following is my html structure:

```
    <div id="div-wrap">

            <div class="column-1-7"> ... </div>

            <div class="column-2-7"> ... </div>

            <div class="column-3-7"> ... </div>

   </div>
```

Below is my css structure:

```
#div-wrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.column-1-7,.column-2-7,.column-3-7 {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;

}

.column-1-7{
    background: #ffcc00;
}
.column-2-7{
    background: #ffff00;
}
.column-3-7{
    background: #ffccff;
}
```

Comment: this is almost good. The thing is that column 1 and 3 to have a max width of 35px and the only one who is going to change the with is column 2